# how can i remove the Site Collection logo section

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, page-layout

by default any site collection will have a logo at the left side corner, but i am unable to remove the whole logo section ? can anyone advice on this ? since if i remove the Logo URL it will automatically show the SharePoint logo , even if no logo URL is specified ?

**EDIT**

I added this inside the  tag but the layout have break :-

```
<head runat="server">
td.s4-titlelogo{ display: none; }
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>
```

did i added the `td.s4-titlelogo{ display: none; }` in the right way and in the right place ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to apply css on the master page to hide the logo, if you change the logo Url in the site settings page to become an empty value, it will default to the SharePoint's default logo.

You need to place this css in the master page head tag (for testing), or preferably in an external css file, but for testing, open the master page, locate the head tag, and place this code inside:

```
 td.s4-titlelogo{
    display: none;
 }
```

When you see it works and everything is fine, insert the css in a .css file in the style library and reference this file in your master page.

Comment: thanks for the reply. do you mean to add this to the v4.master from SharePoint designer ?

Comment: Yes, first copy the v4.master, paste it in the same folder (using SharePoint Designer), then rename the master page to a new meaningful name, right click on the new master page, set it as system and site master page. Then open the master page, and insert this code into <head> tag. 

When it works, remove the css, create a new .css file in Style Library, paste the code in the css file, reference the  .css in your master page.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but when i copy the v4.master and i tried to set the new v4.master as the default master page. i will get a message that this master page is intended with pages version 4 while current the version is 15 . any idea why i am getting this message ?

Comment: ah, you are using SharePoint 2013 then, so you are using either oslo.master or seatle.master, you can copy any of these master pages instead of the v4 and do the same process.

Comment: yes SharePoint 2013 ..

Comment: i think i understand your point,, but as i did not work on the SharePoint designer before, so i am not sure how i can add a custom css and refer this custom css inside the seatle.master page ?

Comment: You can use like this: 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link to your css file inside style library"/>

The only thing you need to change in this line is the value of href. 

There are better ways to reference css in SharePoint, and some depend on if you are using SharePoint Server or Foundation, but you will be ready to go with this one above.

Comment: Did you try the css snippet I provided in the <head> tag first?

Comment: adding the td.s4-titlelogo{ display: none; } inside the <head> tag in my deatle.master , will break the whole layout for the team site, can you check my edit to see if i added it in the right way.

Comment: You'll need to add it inside <style> tags in your head, so the html will understand it's a style sheet. Copy and Paste the following in your <head> tag: 

<style type="text/css">
 td.s4-titlelogo{ display: none; } 
 </style>

Comment: i added your code,but still the default SharePoint logo will be displayed? any idea why it did not work ?

Comment: OK, yes you're using SharePoint 2013, sorry for that, you would need to write this instead: 
<style type="text/css">
div#DeltaSiteLogo{ display: none;}
</style>

The code I provided previously is for SP2010, now it should work for you.

Comment: thanks your code it removed the logo, but still the logo area will be empty space . i though that hiding the logo area will allow the other components such as left quick lunch links and site contents to occupy the old logo space. any idea how i can shift the quick lunch to the upper most to occupay the logo space ?

Comment: Will you try to replace the div#DeltaSiteLogo with div#siteIcon, it should work this way :)

Comment: thank a lot ,, but seems modifying the SP page layout is not that easy .

Comment: It's easy if you know where to begin